# Twilio - how well does the "Add Attachment" beta feature work in the chat?

Tags: twilio, chat, attachment

i want users to be able to add attachments to their chat, currently it says this is in beta testing. Does anyone know when it will be fully released and/or how well it works now?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking how a feature works or when it will be released.

Answer (score 0):

Adding attachments to chat works. [When Twilio describes a product or feature as beta it means](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002413087-Twilio-Beta-Product-Support):

> Products and features in pilot, developer preview, and public beta are not covered by Twilio support agreements, and will not be supported via chat or paid phone support until after production launch. Customer help requests for some developer preview and public beta may be handled by Twilio engineers to improve those products for general availability release. Because these help requests are handled by our engineering team, responses may take longer.
>
> Additionally, the product documentation is evolving as the engineering team fixes bug and improves the product for GA. So you may experience some gaps or changes as the product is refined.
>
> Lastly, there may be some compatibility issues between our officially released, GA products and beta products. Take care in where you put beta products in your stack and how wide you roll it out.